# Facebook page/cursor next

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I would like to get comments for the post. I know how to make it. A response contains parameter next page, previous page or the same next cursor, previous cursor. May I make request to next\previous page after a few hours? E.g. if few comments have been removed, does it change cursors?

Answer (score 0):

The cursor will be invalidated as stated at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

> Unless this item is deleted, the cursor will always point to the same part of the list, but it will be invalidated if an item is removed.

Comment: what does it mean? invalidated? For example, i red 10 of 12 comments(0-read,1-read,...9-read, 10-unread(next cursor returns start here), 11-unread), and store next-cursor. After a few hours some people deleted  their comments(10 was deleted, and 5 was deleted) and other people wrote some comments(in old indexes 12, 13, 14). When i go now to "stored next-cursor", will i get 11, 12, 13, 14? or I get smth else?